# Did Putin tell George W. Bush that Putin's dog was "bigger, stronger and faster" than Bush's dog?

Tags: vladimir-putin

In a [September 2023 interview](https://youtu.be/2954AVJr5pI?t=389) of [George W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush), he relates a story about Vladimir Putin's "chip on his shoulder":

> I discovered it when I introduced him to
> my little dog, Barney, who's a Scottish
> terrier and he kind of dissed him, you know,
> like "You can't call that thing a dog."
>
> Anyway, a year later Laura and I go visit
> him, outside of Moscow, and he said
> "You want to meet my dog?"
> I had forgotten about the Barney diss, of
> course, and I said "Yeah", and out bounds a
> huge Russian Hound, and he looks at me and goes "Bigger,
> stronger and faster than Barney!"
>
> I tell this Canadian Prime Minister
> and he goes "At least he only showed you
> his dog!"

Are there other accounts confirming this story, especially from the Russian side?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Putin's dog Konni was a Labrador, not a "huge Russian hound". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pets_of_Vladimir_Putin - the page lists a few other dogs, but they were gifted to Putin after 2009, so probably after the meeting took place

Comment: the question title uses the word "better" which struck me as the most interesting part of the claim, however the question states "bigger", a much less stinging joke, especially when comparing to an obviously smaller dog.

Comment: @Spork: fair enough. It was my mistake when transcribing the claim initially. Still, it's not the factuality of the comparison, but the political lack of adroitness in saying something like that to Bush's face that's questionable aspect here. At least in public, Putin is often very polite with foreign leaders.

Comment: @Spork: observers [did](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-66509180) point out that Russian diplomacy [publicly] became more shrill after 2015, but this exchange surely happened before then.

Comment: The story is in his (Bush's) memoir, his press secretary's memoir, and a Politico article. But for Russian sources all I can find is a review of the Bush book. Would you consider that proof enough of the exchange's happening?

Comment: @CDR: what does the review say?

Comment: @CDR: FWTW, I found that Putin was introduced to bigger dogs from Bush's family http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/media/images/42451000/jpg/_42451570_ap416palm.jpg

Comment: [It](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/1536223) doesn't really add much to Bush's account. It basically sniffs that Bush talks about his dog more than he does about the Australian PM and reports the same incident.

Comment: Not about Bush, but it seems that Merkel is afraid of dogs, and Putin enjoyed trying to make her feel uneasy with his dog in front of the cameras.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBCDd6LUneg